# Google apps script - Speeding up getActiveDocument()?

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm working on a script to set to uppercase a selected text in a Google document. The script works ok, but it is extremely slow in a large document. So I stripped down almost everything to perform some speed test and I realised that this simple line:

```
      var document = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
```

already takes 9-10 seconds to perform for a 150 pages document.

Is there a way to speed up the process, i.e. precaching "document" so that when I invoke my script I can use my `getCursor()` or `getSelection()` in a reasonable time?

Comment: Why not just throw it in global scope?  It'll run when you first open the doc.

Comment: @BryanP I tried to declare the variable as global but it didn't make any difference. I think it's been refreshed every time you run the script (which makes sense, since the document changes as you edit).

Comment: The global `var document` won't change on edit of the doc.  How are you invoking the script?  Post the rest of the code that you think is relavant to the delay.

Comment: Ok, yea it will look at the globals each time any function is run so ignore that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't precache this. 
The services provided for caching are:

- CacheService : only store String values
- ScriptDB : can't store Document on this.

So I'm afraid that you will need to cope with it.